Proof that no tetration of pi(integer tetration) can be an integer
I have heard that it is an unsolved problem whether numbers like $\pi^{\pi^{\pi^\pi}}$ are integers. It seems obvious to me that $\pi^{\pi^{\cdots^\pi}}$ should never be an integer. I thought I could prove it, but I'm sure that it can't be this simple, because otherwise it wouldn't still be an open problem. What is wrong with the following proof?
Theorem: Let $x_n$ represent the result of a finite tower of $n$ exponents of $\pi$, defined recursively as:
$$
    x_1 = \pi, \quad x_{n+1} = \pi^{x_n}.
$$
Then, $x_n$ is not an integer for any $n \geq 1$.
Proof: We proceed by contradiction. Assume that $x_n$ is an algebraic integer $k$ for some finite $n \geq 1$. Thus, at the $n$-th level of the tower, we have:
$$
    \pi^{x_{n-1}} = k, \quad \text{where $k$ is an integer.}
$$
Taking the natural logarithm of both sides, we obtain:
$$
    x_{n-1} \cdot \log(\pi) = \log(k).
$$
Now, the term $\log(k)$ is transcendental for any integer $k > 1$ (due to the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem), so the equation involves a transcendental number $\log(k)$.
Step 1: Contradiction From the equation $x_{n-1} \cdot \log(\pi) = \log(k)$, we can solve for $x_{n-1}$:
$$
    x_{n-1} = \frac{\log(k)}{\log(\pi)}.
$$
Since $\log(\pi)$ is transcendental, and $\log(k)$ is transcendental for $k > 1$, the ratio $\frac{\log(k)}{\log(\pi)}$ is transcendental as well.
This shows that $x_{n-1}$ is transcendental, which contradicts our assumption that $x_n = k$ was an integer.
Step 2: Conclusion Since the assumption that $x_n$ is an integer leads to a contradiction, $x_n$ must be transcendental for all finite $n$. The transcendence of $\pi$ propagates through the entire structure of the tower, ensuring that $x_n$ is transcendental at every level.

Knowing that a number is algebraic doesn't tell you it is an integer.  knowing that $\alpha, \beta $ are transcendental does not tell you that $\frac {\alpha}{\beta}$ is.

Can we at least do this "$\pi^\pi$ is transcendental"?

it isnt an integer that is what i mean

There are two critical errors: First,in Step 1:

Since $\log(\pi)$ is transcendental, and $\log(k)$ is transcendental for $k>1$, the ratio $\frac{\log(\pi)}{\log k}$ is transcendental as well.

A ratio of transcendental numbers can be anything except $0$. For instance, $\pi$ and $2\pi$ are both transcendental, but $\frac{\pi}{2\pi}=\frac12\in\mathbb{Q}$.
Second, in the logic: In step 1 you purport to prove that if $x_n$ is an integer, then $x_{n-1}$ is transcendental. However, there is no reason why $x_{n-1}$ being transcendental would contradict $x_n$ being algebraic or an integer. All of the following are logically possible: $\pi^a$ and $a$ are both transcendental, $\pi^a$ is algebraic but $a$ is not, or $\pi^a$ is transcendental but $a$ is algebraic. Even $\pi^a$ and $a$ both algebraic is possible with $a=0$. So, while $\pi^a$ being algebraic for nonzero $a$ would imply that $a$ is transcendental, $a$ being transcendental has no implications about $\pi^a$.

but wouldnt k then be a non integer

Perhaps. I just noticed there's another mistake in the proof as well. Let me update my answer.

thank you very much
